# How to show Dialog Vuetify from Component Parent via v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to open my dialog Modal (compenent child) of the component Parent
but it doesn't work with v:bind props. someone can help me please,
here is my code component Parent

```js
showDialog: function () {
      //console.log(item);
      this.active_dialog=true;
  },
```

```html
<v-col cols="12" md="3" class="text-end">
    <good-dialog 
      v-bind:updateIndex="updateIndex" 
      v-bind:item="item" 
      v-bind:active_dialog="active_dialog">
    </good-dialog>
</v-col>
<v-btn
  elevation="0"
  class="mx-2"
  fab
  dark
  small
  color="primary"
  @click="showDialog()"
>
  <v-icon small>fa-edit</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

and here is my child component

```js
export default {
  props:{
    updateIndex:Number,
    item:Object,
    active_dialog:Boolean
  },
  name: "GoodDialog",
  data() {
    return {     
      showDialog:this.active_dialog,

    };
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-dialog v-model="showDialog" persistent max-width="400">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> Nouveau Biens </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>
```